# Setting non string variable using PyYaml

Tags: python, pyyaml, mkdocs

I am using mkdocs system which is configured using yaml file, parsed via PyYml. I want to be able to specificy environment variable in its `mkdocs.yml` which is not possible in mkdocs ecosystem, but workaround exists using PyYml special `!!python/object/apply:os.getenv` syntax which works great for yaml keys of type string.

However, this doesn't work:

```
plugins:
    - search
    - pdf-export:
        combined: !!python/object/apply:os.getenv ["PDF_EXPORT_COMBINED"]
```

The build complains that string is not bool value:

```
PS> $Env:PDF_EXPORT_COMBINED='true'
PS> mkdocs build
...
ERROR - Config value: 'plugins'. Error: Plugin value: 'combined'. 
        Expected type: <class 'bool'> but received: <class 'str'>
```

I looked into PyYAML section *YAML tags and Python types*[^1](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) to no avail. I guess form:

> !python/object/apply:module.f | value of f(...)

could be used as I need pythons `distutils.util.strtobool( os.getenv("PDF_EXPORT_COMBINED") )` but not sure if that is possible using that syntax.

Comment: You should  make your own module `x` with a function `y` that does both the getenv and strtobool and then run `!python/object/apply:x.y ["PDF_EXPORT_COMBINED"] instead of trying to nest function calls and hope apply takes care of things.

Comment: Thx, not sure how to do that in the context of external tool tho, but I guess it could be done.

Comment: If you have installed mkdocs via your package manager look at the header of the command, it should show you which python it uses (or use `which` etc) it used. If you have installed mkdocs with pip you know which virtualenv you used. In either case just store your module in `lib/pythonXY/site-packages` next to the `bin` directory that holds the python executable.